# Codeigniter Active Record - where time from timestamp is greater than

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, timestamp

I am trying to compare the time from a timestamp with the current time.

I currently have the following line:

```
$this->db->where('period_end >', $time);
```

But this compares `1995-04-08 13:00:00` against `10:43:44`

What i want to compare is `13:00:00` against `10:43:44` and ignore the date completely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the time part from datatime field by using `DATE_FORMAT`,Also using this approach you need to pass third parameter as `FALSE` to avoid addition of backticks by active record

```
$this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(period_end,'%H:%i:%s') >", $time,FALSE);
```

[*Small demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35282)